# Is CSV a structured or semi-structured data?

Tags: csv

I am confused about whether CSV is a structured data or a semi-structured data.
While RDBMS is a structured data with relations, CSV files lack relations.
I am not able to find the exact answer.

Answer (score 6):

As far I can say, CSV with constant columns and rows (two dimensions)can be mentioned as structured data as it can be easily queried. But when there are multi-dimensional columns and rows, then it can be considered as semi-structured data.

Comment: If you talk of a specific case CSV format 'with constant' columns you could argue its structured - but that's like saying JSON that conforms to scheme is structured. If CSV can generally be interpreted with 'schema on read' and not required at time of writing, I'd say semi-structured is a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

CSV files are Semi- Structured files. Semi structured data does not have the same level of organization as structured data like relational database. Here the data contain elements that can separate the data into various hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

CSV, like JSON and XML or their variants, is SEMI-STRUCTURED data because it may contain hierachical data/tables.